# The derived representation and $H_\pi^\infty$

Tags: rt.representation-theory, gr.group-theory

There is some (probably stupid) thing that I did not get in Serge Lang's  [$SL_2(\mathbf{R})$](http://books.google.de/books?id=eD_XRsPv0WkC&lpg=PP1&dq=sl2&pg=PA93#v=onepage&q&f=false): On page 93 he considers a representation $\pi:G\to GL(H)$ of a group $G$ in a Banach space. Then he defines the subspace $H_\pi^\infty$ as
$$
H_\pi^\infty = \{v\in H\ |\ x\mapsto \pi(x)v\ \text{ is }\ C^\infty \}
$$
and uses this to define the derived representation.

My question simply is: Since $G$ is just a group: How is differentiability of the maps $F_v: G \to H$, $F_v(x) = \pi(x)v$ defined?

Comment: The group $G$ must be a Lie group for this to make sense, so it has a differentiable structure.

Comment: Sorry for the stupid question and thanks for the totally non-stupid answer!